# Require assistance with simple pure Java 11 WebSocket client example

Tags: websocket, java-11, java-http-client

There appears to be very little Java 11 (pure Java non framework based) WebSocket **client** code examples on the web so I'm hoping StackOverflow can come to the rescue for me once again.

[This](https://craftsmen.nl/java-11-is-here-to-stay/) is the closest I've found, but unfortunately to my (novice) eyes, it doesn't appear to be a complete solution in showing how to consume the data from the WebSocket listener.

Looking at the [WebSocket.Listener implementation, the onText](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/WebSocket.Listener.html#onText(java.net.http.WebSocket,java.lang.CharSequence,boolean)) callback method I presume would provide what I need, but I'm struggling to figure out how to return the CompletionStage object and some sort of string data from the socket.

This is some test code I have so far.

Would appreciate assistance. Thanks

```java
    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

           WebSocketClient wsc = new WebSocketClient();
           wsc.startSocket("ws://demos.kaazing.com/echo");

           int i = 0;   

           // Bad, very bad
           do {} while (i == 0);
        }
    }


    public class WebSocketClient implements WebSocket.Listener {

        @Override
        public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket) {
           //...
            System.out.println("Go...Open".concat(
                    webSocket.getSubprotocol()));
        }

        @Override
        public CompletionStage<?> onText(WebSocket webSocket, CharSequence data, boolean last) {
           //...
            System.out.println(data.toString());

            // How do I return the CompletionStage object
            // return CompletionStage<String>
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable error) {
           //..
            System.out.println("Bad day! ".concat(webSocket.toString()));
        }

        void startSocket(String connection) {
            CompletableFuture<WebSocket> server_cf = HttpClient.
                    newHttpClient().
                    newWebSocketBuilder().
                    buildAsync(URI.create(connection),
                            new WebSocketClient());
            WebSocket server = server_cf.join();
            server.sendText("Hello!", true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not really concerned (as I just would like some help), but if you're going to downvote, it would be great if you could at least say what's wrong.

Comment: Do you know why `CompletionStage` needs to be returned from `on`-methods of `Listener`? In other words, what purpose do these stages serve?

Answer (score 18):

Below you find a working example. I have made some changes to your code above:

- `onOpen` needs to invoke `request(1)` on the websocket (invoking the default implementation) in order to receive further invocations.
- moved method `startSocket` into the main method
- replaced busy waiting with a count down latch
- declared class `WebSocketClient` as a (static) inner class

but beyond these (cosmetic) changes the program follows your idea, i.e. first a websocket connection is build and after successful construction the text *Hello!* is sent to the echo server. This could also be done in method `onOpen` directly.

```java
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.WebSocket;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
        
public class Main {
        
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        
        WebSocket ws = HttpClient
                .newHttpClient()
                .newWebSocketBuilder()
                .buildAsync(URI.create("ws://demos.kaazing.com/echo"), new WebSocketClient(latch))
                .join();
        ws.sendText("Hello!", true);
        latch.await();
    }
            
    private static class WebSocketClient implements WebSocket.Listener {
        private final CountDownLatch latch;
                
        public WebSocketClient(CountDownLatch latch) { this.latch = latch; }
        
        @Override
        public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket) {
            System.out.println("onOpen using subprotocol " + webSocket.getSubprotocol());
            WebSocket.Listener.super.onOpen(webSocket);
        }
        
        @Override
        public CompletionStage<?> onText(WebSocket webSocket, CharSequence data, boolean last) {
            System.out.println("onText received " + data);
            latch.countDown();
            return WebSocket.Listener.super.onText(webSocket, data, last);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onError(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable error) {
            System.out.println("Bad day! " + webSocket.toString());
            WebSocket.Listener.super.onError(webSocket, error);
        }
    }
}
```

Btw, no supprotocol was negotiated, therefore method `webSocket.getSubprotocol()` returns an empty string. The output in the console is

```
    onOpen using subprotocol 
    onText received Hello!
```

Comment: You don't need to call `WebSocket.Listener.super.onXXX` methods religiously. It all depends on your needs. In particular, `onError` specifies that:
`@implSpec The default implementation does nothing`

Comment: @pavel, you are right, thanks for the comment. All the super-calls could be dropped (and `onText` could return `null` instead), but then in method `onOpen` the statement `webSocket.request(1)` would have to be executed in order to enable the websocket to invoke at least one receive method (this was missing in the original example).

Comment: Hi, In case I want to send authentication data to the websocket server to get connected how do we do this. I was able to establish the web socket connection using JavaScript successfully. Below is the JSON object I send to the WS conncetion => jsonSendObj = {
      "channel":"",
      "task":"cn",
      "acctid":UID,
      "user":UID,
      "token": userSessionID
     };  How do we send this using Java? Can we use teh same SetString method?

Answer (score 1):

The pattern for managing a WebSocket response returning a `CompletionStage` is:

```java
@Override
public CompletionStage<?> onText(WebSocket webSocket, CharSequence data, boolean last) {
    // return inmmediately but response is geenrated lazyly.
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        String response = "Received  ...";
        // do slow task. Access to database or access to a server.
        return response;
    });
}
```

This simple implementation only is recommended when the response is generated quickly.

```java
@Override
public CompletionStage<?> onText(WebSocket webSocket, CharSequence data, boolean last) {
    // fast response.
    String response = "The text has " + data.length() + " chars";
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had some trouble getting various examples working.  Specifically, I had trouble finding examples that actually showed how to open, send, and receive simple text messages.  One important piece was having a server to which to connect.  Here is what I managed to make work.

```java
    package webSockets;
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URI;
    
    import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
    import javax.websocket.ContainerProvider;
    import javax.websocket.Endpoint;
    import javax.websocket.EndpointConfig;
    import javax.websocket.MessageHandler;
    import javax.websocket.Session;
    import javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer;
    
    public class SimpleWebsocketClient extends Endpoint {
        private Session session;
    
        public SimpleWebsocketClient() {}
    
        public SimpleWebsocketClient(URI endpointURI) {
            try {
                WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
                container.connectToServer(this, endpointURI);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
      
        @Override
        public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason reason){
            System.out.println("Disconnected as a result of "+ reason.getReasonPhrase());
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Session session, Throwable error){
            System.out.println("Error communicating with server: " + error.getMessage());
        }
        @Override
        public void onOpen(Session s, EndpointConfig config) {
            System.out.println("Session opened");
            session = s;
            session.addMessageHandler(new MessageHandler.Whole<String>() {
    
                @Override
                public void onMessage(String msg) {
                    System.out.println("Text Message Received:" + msg);
                }
            });
            try {
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hello there.");
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hope you are well!");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
        
        public static void main(String...arg) {
            URI uri = URI.create("ws://connect.websocket.in/v3/1?api_key=oCdCMcMPQpbvNjUIzqtvF1d2X2okWpDQj4AwARJuAgtjhzKxVEjQU6IdCjwm&notify_self");
            new SimpleWebsocketClient(uri);
            while(true) {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note this is using the JavaEE `javax.websockets` support, not the Java 11 SE `java.net.http.WebSocket` support the OP requested.

Comment: right you are.  Sorry for polluting the discussion.